# How to stay always logged in with Level 3 Perforce security (ticket based)?

Tags: security, authentication, perforce

I'm trying to find a way to stay logged into my Perforce server even using Ticketed / Level 3 security. Is this even possible?

Would it just be safe to set the ticket to never expire? I feel like that defeats the purpose altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the ticket to never expire is what you're looking for -- you're correct that it does create a bit of a security risk in that someone who compromises your client machine while you're absent has easy access to the Perforce server.  With the default 12-hour ticket this is of course still possible, but the window of opportunity doesn't include times when you're away for extended periods.

An unlimited ticket is still more secure than authenticating with a password stored on the client machine (even a hashed password) in a couple of respects:

1. It's bound to your client IP (by default), so someone who gains access to your machine and copies the ticket down can't use it elsewhere.
2. You can invalidate your ticket at any time (without changing your actual password) by doing "p4 logout -a", making a previously stolen ticket useless.